# Installing TypeScript with Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, typescript, npm

i'm trying to install TypeScript with Laravel 5.6 but i'm having errors when I try to run 'npm run dev'. Here's my configuration, what am I doing wrong ?

---

webpack.mix.js

```
 let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.webpackConfig({

    resolve : {
        extensions : ['.ts']
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test : /\.ts$/,
                loader : 'ts-loader' 
            }
        ]
    }
});

    mix.js('resources/assets/ts/app.ts', 'public/js')
       .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "strict": true,                           

  },

  "include": [
    "resources/assets/ts/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel Mix natively supports TypeScript.

You can just do:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.ts('resources/assets/ts/app.ts', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```